# ANTLR String Tokens giving Implicit Definition Warning

Tags: antlr4

So I'm getting the "Implicit definition of token `'x'` in parser rule." warning in parser rules with this format: `rule: 'x' Subrule;` even though all `'x'` values I'm using have been included in a lexer rule. For example, `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'`, etc. are defined as `Operator` tokens. Defining them in a lexer rule with no alternatives (ex: `Add: '+';`) seems to fix the problem. Could someone explain what's going on and if there's a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you still have literals in your parser rules. It is good practice to only define lexer tokens in lexer rules. Follow that rule and these warnings will be gone.